# JpegBitmapEncoder QualityLevel has no effect

Tags: c#, wpf, image-processing

I want to save an Image as an Jpeg with JpegBitmapEncoder but setting the QualityLevel has no effect? The resulting jpeg is always the same size (~4mb for 2200x1500px).

```
        RenderTargetBitmap rtb = new RenderTargetBitmap(collage.Breite, collage.Hoehe, dpi, dpi, System.Windows.Media.PixelFormats.Default);
        canvas.UpdateLayout();
        rtb.Render(canvas);
        JpegBitmapEncoder jpgEncoder = new JpegBitmapEncoder();
        jpgEncoder.QualityLevel = 35; // no effect, Image to big
        jpgEncoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(rtb));
        using (var fs = System.IO.File.OpenWrite(myfilename, variables)))
        {
            jpgEncoder.Save(fs);
            fs.Close();
            fs.Dispose();
        }
```

Comment: As a note, you neither need to call `fs.Close()` nor `fs.Dispose()`. The using block does all that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed it to:

```
var fs = new FileStream(myfilename, variables), FileMode.Create);

jpgEncoder.Save(fs); 
fs.Close();
```

Comment: This doesn't make sense, and it won't compile. What is the `myfilename, variables` combination actually? You probably had the file name wrong in your original code, and were looking at a different file?